# What does Mad Moxxi's tip jar in Sanctuary do?

Tags: borderlands-2

What does Mad Moxxi's tip jar in Sanctuary do? You can tip her either $100 or $1000.

Comment: If you have excess money I don't recommend tipping her as the weapons aren't that good. Instead play her slot machines. This will win you guns, and Eridium. I used this to max all my eridium early in the game. So now I have 27 bag slots, full ammo capacity... etc

Comment: But what about [Mad Moxxii's Good Touch](http://youtu.be/jbZ44RCpOpc)? Slot machine provides eridium and some good weapons, but Moxxii has many just fun weapons.

Comment: This question "How many times can you get Moxxi's Good/Bad Touch weapon?" http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/86125/27963 might also be night to add here.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

### An achievement and guns. (No cutscenes.)

The **"Sugar Daddy" achievement** unlocks at $10,000 cumulatively donated. You can exit the game without saving to keep the achievement and your money.

Moxxi hands over **two guns** (and variants whereof):

- **[Miss Moxxi's Bad Touch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HSDwY.png)**, a red, corrosive SMG
- **[Miss Moxxi's Good Touch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PcHPr.jpg)**, a purple, incendiary SMG, vibrates your controller when in use

The Bad Touch triggers between 5k and 20k, and the Good Touch between 10k and 50k (when tipping in $1000 increments). This amount could be random—reports are inconclusive.

You [can](http://forums.gearboxsoftware.com/showpost.php?p=2796931&postcount=43) return to (or reload) Sanctuary for more Good Touches, but reportedly, there is only one Bad Touch per playthrough. The variants (e.g., ["Guileless"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ziVgz.png) and "Impetuous") tend to have lower stats. The guns' level reqs scale to your story progress. You can always restart your game from the last save if you don't like your results.

[image: Miss Moxxi's Good Touch]

Comment: Can you get the guns multiple times? If you keep donating?

Comment: Hm I don't think the $ amount is right. She just seems to randomly give the guns when you spam her with $100 bills. I've gotten several and almost certainly paid less than 5k total after switching to 100s

Comment: Just to note, no prefix flatly lowers damage. Impetuous subtracts a bit of damage for a huge increase in projectile speed. This is very favorable considering Maliwan's slow bullets, even more so for Plasma Casters.

Comment: And because they are Moxxi weapons, they heal you.

Answer (score 17):

Tipping her $10000 gets an achievement.

Comment: She also gives you two guns, really nice ones too!

Comment: This answer is incorrect.  There is no cutscene, and it fails to list the guns that are available as rewards at higher tip levels.

Comment: @bwarner Answer has been updated to remove the incorrect part about the cutscene.

Answer (score 10):

I have gotten two guns. the first at $20,000 she says isn't her favorite then at $50,000 is her favorite gun and to use it to see why

Answer (score 3):

According to this [link](http://www.gameranx.com/updates/id/9474/article/borderlands-2-sexy-easter-egg-mad-moxxi-s-vibrating-gun/) if you give her 15 000$ in tips you could get a vibrating gun that make the 2nd controller vibrate all the time for the ladies :D

Note: you could get 2 weapons: Moxxi's Good Touch (as described above) or Moxxi's Bad Touch, which doesn't vibrate.

Comment: Why only for the ladies? :D

Comment: This is the funniest comment I've read so far

Answer (score 1):

The first time you tip her $10000 you just get an achievement and a badass rank. Each additional time you tip her $10000, you get a weapon - usually it's quite good.

Comment: Are there more than 2 guns?

Comment: I don't know. I guess I assumed prematurely. Did you stop getting guns after the first two?

Comment: Everything I've read has said there are only two.

Comment: is the gun a leveled gun?  I.e. is it worth it to wait on the tipping until you are at max level?

Comment: I got the Badass Rank, Achievement, and one purple weapon at my level after the first $10000 tip. I was around level 12 at the time.