# Moxxi's Good touch gun

Tags: borderlands-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does Mad Moxxi’s tip jar in Sanctuary do?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/84799/what-does-mad-moxxis-tip-jar-in-sanctuary-do)

I have already tipped Moxxi 10000 like it said on the internet. I still haven't got any gun yet. Please help me, I really want that gun. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Better to tip her in one go thats how I got that gun and well I had to tip her 30+ times, Maybe the tipping amount is somehow related to your current level(I am not so sure about this).

Before giving her gun she will say something like "this is my favorite gun"